# How to fix vshost32.exe has stopped working without doing the same thing every new project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-7-x64

Iv'e had that problem for long time and then I found the solution of disabling visual studio hosting process or enabling native code debugging every time in the properties of the project,but its been really annoying and I don't even know if I need those functions and dose it hurt my projects so I want to know if there is a solution without doing it every new project and will not have negative effect on my projects,using Visual studio 2012 express and win7 64bit.
thank you for the help.

Comment: Heck of an XY question.  Just create your own project template with File > Export Template.

Comment: what do you mean? enable native code debugging and then create new template? and how do I open it every time I start new project?